# Python: Why does the dict.fromkeys method not produce a working dicitonary

Tags: python, dictionary

I had the following dictionary:

```
ref_range = range(0,100)
aas = list("ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWXY*")
new_dict = {}
new_dict = new_dict.fromkeys(ref_range,{k:0 for k in aas})
```

Then I added a 1 to a specific key

```
new_dict[30]['G'] += 1

>>>new_dict[30]['G']
1
```

but

```
>>>new_dict[31]['G']
1
```

What is going on here? I only incremented the nested key 30, 'G' by one.

Note: If I generate the dictionary this way:

```
new_dict = {}
for i in ref_range:
   new_dict[i] = {a:0 for a in aas}
```

Everything behaves fine. I think this is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654646/how-do-i-create-a-unique-value-for-each-key-using-dict-fromkeys), but I wanted to know a bit about why this happening rather than how to solve it.

Comment: Existing answer is correct, just providing the one-liner for making `new_dict`: `new_dict = {i: dict.fromkeys(aas, 0) for i in ref_range}`. Alternatively, make a template `dict`: `template = dict.fromkeys(aas, 0)`, then shallow copy it over and over: `new_dict = {i: template.copy() for i in ref_range}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromkeys(S, v)` sets all of the keys in `S` to the same value `v`. Meaning that all of the keys in your dictionary `new_dict` refer to the same dictionary object, not to their own copies of that dictionary.

To set each to a different dict object you cannot use `fromkeys`. You need to just set each key to a new dict in a loop.

Besides what you have you could also do

```
{i: {a: 0 for a in aas} for i in ref_range}
```

Comment: do you think there should be a warning generated or something? I mean, its not very intuitive right off the bat.