# If dict().fromkeys() all point to the same object, what purpose does the default value argument serve?

Tags: python, dictionary

The dict method `{}.fromkeys()` takes an iterable of strings, which will be transformed into dictionary keys. The default value will default to `None`. For instance:

```
d = {}.fromkeys(['loss', 'val_loss'])
```

```
{'loss': None, 'val_loss': None}
```

An optional, second argument is the default value that all these values will take:

```
d = {}.fromkeys(['loss', 'val_loss'], [])
```

```
{'loss': [], 'val_loss': []}
```

I understand that you can initialize an empty dict like this. Where it gets more complicated is that the **default values point to the same object**.

```
[id(val) for val in d.values()]
```

```
[140711273848032, 140711273848032]
```

If you would append one list, it would append all the values of this dict. Therefore, you need to re-assign the values to a new object in order to treat the dict values as separate objects:

```
d['loss'] = list([0.2, 0.4])
```

If you don't do that, you will change all dict values at the same time.

**My question: what purpose is the optional default value intended to serve?**

As I see it, you will need to reassign this default value anyway, unless you want to manipulate the same object with different dict keys. I can't think of an honest reason to have many dict keys for one object.

Comment: The purpose of the optional default value is to be a default value instead of `None`, as you observed. That this is the same object for every key is only problematic if it is a mutable object, like a list or dictionary. If you want a dictionary with a list or dictionary as default value if you look up a non existent key, you should use a `defaultdict` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dict.fromkeys all point to same list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516413/dict-fromkeys-all-point-to-same-list)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654646/how-do-i-create-a-unique-value-for-each-key-using-dict-fromkeys

Comment: i know how to use a `defaultdict`, and that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) "fromkeys() is a class method that returns a new dictionary. value defaults to None. All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead."

Comment: please stop the dupe-hammering. these do not answer my question. i know how to use dict comprehension to create new objects, and i know how to do this another way. the mutable part could be an answer to my question, however

Comment: Can you clarify what *is* your question? The part you've highlighted in bold has the obvious answer "the purpose is that you can specify the default value in case you don't like `None`". But I guess you know that from the documentation so I don't understand what is unclear to you.

Comment: you answered it pretty well in the second sentence of your first comment

Answer (score 3):

This can work ( dictionary comprehension)

```
keys = {'A', 'B', 'C'}
int_lst = [9]
a_dict = { key : list(int_lst) for key in keys }
print(a_dict)
a_dict['B'].append(12)
print(a_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my question is not "what else could work", I know how to use dict comprehension.